# Silence qgis.core error messages in reticulate

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, r

I am using the `qgis.core` Python module in R using `reticulate`. I start the QgsApplication using the following code.

```
# Start reticulate
reticulate::use_python(Sys.getenv("PYTHONHOME"), require = TRUE)

# Import modules
qgis.core <- reticulate::import("qgis.core")

# Create QGIS application
qgs <- qgis.core$QgsApplication(integer(), TRUE)

# Initiate QGIS application.
qgs$initQgis()
```

For whatever reason, I get the following messages when I run the `qgs$initQgis()` line:

```
ERROR: Opening of authentication db FAILED
ERROR: Unable to establish authentication database connection
ERROR: Auth db could not be created and opened
```

These are just printed to the R console, they do not interrupt the rest of the function or impact the rest of the code. These errors have also been reported as being inconsequential by other users: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38175594/5106834

It would be great if the error messages could not appear, but failing that, I would at least like to suppress the messages. So far I have tried `suppressMessages()`, `sink()`, `invisible()` and `capture.output()` and none have worked.

How can I silence these error messages?

Comment: What's your operating system, or do you  need a solution for multiple operating systems? Are you running R in a batch script, or in an interactive session using either a plain R terminal or RStudio or another R UI?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am using RStudio. If you mean running from a .bat file, then no, but the code I posted is within an R function. I only need a solution for Windows systems.

Comment: Have you tried `reticulate::py_capture_output`?